# How to increase speed of accessing large amount of data in google cloud SQL

Tags: sql, cloud

I tried store an image file into `MEDIUMBLOB` at google cloud sql. but it can store only less than 1k. I want to store 6K file. How can i solve this problem? or do i have to split it and store? It take me 4 days but i have even got any hint.

if i upload more than 1k, it shows a message:

> Some values in the result set were truncated.

This is sql code in server

```
statement = "INSERT INTO picture (registration_id, pic) VALUES( ?, ?)";
stmt = c.prepareStatement(statement);
stmt.setString(1, sender_id);
stmt.setBytes(2, message.getBytes());

int success = 2;
success = stmt.executeUpdate();`
```

please help me

- Thank you for your answer to use `LONGBLOB` .
  but i tried it before and it turned out that it still can only less than 1kbyte.
  I think that there is a volume limitation in google cloud sql.
  Is there anyone else who knows about it?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to a LONGBLOB

Comment: Thank you for your answer to use LONGBLOB .
but i tried it before and it turned out that it still can only less than 1kbyte.
I think that there is a volume limitation in google cloud sql.
Is there anyone else who knows about it?